# Copy Data in Uncompressed ZFS Filesystem to Another Compressed ZFS Pool

Tags: ubuntu, files, filesystems, zfs, storage

I have 300GB of data in ZFS filesystem `tank/storage` where compression is not enabled. `tank` is a mirror vdev made up of 2 drives `sda` and `sdb` and `tank/storage` is mounted to `/storage`.

I want to know the compression ratio of my data if `lz4` compression is used, so I have created a second ZFS pool `pool` using `sdc` and `sdd` with filesystem `pool/storage` where compressed is enabled.  `pool/storage` is mounted to `/storageCompressed`.

What is the recommended way to copy the data in `/storage` to `/storageCompressed`?

Previously, I tried using `cp -R /storage/database /storageCompressed`, but pressed Ctrl+C in the middle of copying, and all my files in `/storage/database` went missing. I restored my database from a backup and am planning to try again using a more robust method.

Using Ubuntu 16.04, ZFS, 4x 500GB SSDs `sda`, `sdb`, `sdc` and `sdd`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want co make replica of of data from first pool to second pool and have no data on second pool you can create snapshot on first pool.

```
zfs snapshot -r tank@snapshotname
```

then copy the data

```
zfs send -Rv tank@snapshotname|zfs recv -F pool
```

Comment: The argument to `zfs recv` is a filesystem not a pool.

Comment: @schily, AFAIK is the stream is full it can be pool, if its not full it should be filesystem

Comment: Well in fact, there is a filesystem with the name of each pool....this fs is used for the mountpoint.